# xcode 4 not showing main project window

Tags: xcode, cordova

Today I just opened the project I was working on XCODE 4, and only one XML file is being shown... the main editor window with the file explorer seems to be hidden. Is there any way to show it up?

This only happens with a specific project :-S that actually is a phone gap project

THks

Comment: I created a new project, add all existing files, and it works now... but I guess there must be a less painful solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]